# Most efficient way to query for existence of a sequence id indexed values in a Mongo index?

Tags: mongodb

I have a set of documents with an `external-id` field, which is indexed. I have a stream of IDs coming from outside, and I want to find all of those IDs that match a document in the database. I don't care about any of the fields in the database, just the matching ID. The rate at which these come in is significant, so efficiency is important.

In case it affects heuristics, I'm guessing that the proportion that actually do match will be very low.

Solution 1, do it one-by-one:

```
for x in external-ids-stream:
  c = db.documents.count({"external-id": x})
  if c > 0:
    yield x
```

(Excuse the pseudocode.)

Doesn't send too much data over the wire, but probably has a lot of overhead per request.

Solution 2, chunk inputs, $in with projection

```
for xs-chunk in chunks(external-ids-stream):
  docs = db.documents.find({"external-id": {"$in": xs-chunk}}, {"external-id"})
  for doc in docs:
    yield doc.xs-chunk
```

Breaks into chunks, which probably reduces overhead.

I'm guessing #2 is the best of the two, but given that I'm trying to achieve a very specific operation, i.e. intersection of a stream of values against an index, I wonder if there's a more specific and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about number of documents - don't count, but [findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/):

```
db.documents.findOne({"external-id": x}, {"_id":0, "external-id": 1});
```

Be sure the index fit into memory, shard if necessary.

There is not much overhead, as driver keeps connections open in the pool, and on the other hand you can benefit from async requests, processing stream in parallel.

Comment: Thanks! It hadn't occurred to me to use findOne. I'll try it out.

Comment: I've compared the two approaches, 2000 queries (half hit, half miss) in batches of 10, and `$in` is about 4.5x faster.